# API calls working in Expo Go but not in production apk

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I had a problem while logging in the application using the API, but I fixed it by including:

```
{
   "android":{
        "usesCleartextTraffic": true
      }
 }
```

in the app.json,
but now I have another problem the only endpoint that is working is the signin endpoint, any other endpoint is still not working. I get:

```
11-22 11:01:42.985 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS: 'Status:', 500
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS: 'Headers:', { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   connection: 'keep-alive',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   'content-length': '1679',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   date: 'Wed, 22 Nov 2023 08:01:42 GMT',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
11-22 11:01:42.989 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   'x-powered-by': 'Express' }
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS: 'Config:', { transitional:
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:    { silentJSONParsing: true,
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:      forcedJSONParsing: true,
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:      clarifyTimeoutError: false },
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   timeout: 0,
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   maxContentLength: -1,
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   maxBodyLength: -1,
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   env: { FormData: [Function: FormData], Blob: [Function: Blob] },
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   headers:
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:    { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:      'Content-Type': null,
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:      'app-version': '1.0' },
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   method: 'get',
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   url: 'http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:7000/api/v1/userscount',
11-22 11:01:42.994 27146 27174 E ReactNativeJS:   data: undefined }
```

It is a get request. I am not sure why I am getting this.

I tried the endpoint on the dashboard that I made, its working fine and I also checked it using postman still everything is working its only in the production build.

Comment: `Status:', 500` is sent by the server due to an internal error on whatever the server is - `'content-length': '1679'` ... so, what is the content? It may be telling what the problem is

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.